# Changing pages on button click (AngularJS)?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Following online examples, I have something like this in `login.html`:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/app.login.js"></script>

<div id="loginButton" ng-app="loginButton" ng-controller="loginControl">
    <button ng-click="enterSite()">
        Enter
    </button>
</div>
```

Then in `app.login.js`:

```
var appButton = angular.module("loginButton", []);

appButton.controller("loginControl", ["$scope", "$window", function($scope,  $window){
    $scope.enterSite = function(){
        $window.location.href = "../index.html";        
    }
}]);
```

However, it does not redirect to `index.html` when I press the button. There are no errors in the browser's log. I've copied most of the format from working examples, so I cannot find why it does not work for me.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works as it is without any change.

Look in your local system if you see any javascript related issues or script isn't loading from ajax.googleapis.com.

Check if you have linked your login.js properly

```js
var appButton = angular.module("loginButton", []);

appButton.controller("loginControl", ["$scope", "$window", function($scope,  $window){
    $scope.enterSite = function(){
        $window.location.href = "../index.html";        
    }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/app.login.js"></script>

<div id="loginButton" ng-app="loginButton" ng-controller="loginControl">
    <button ng-click="enterSite()">
        Enter
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: You're right, the excerpt I provided worked. However, I embarrassingly used 2 ng-app in login.html (after a bunch of research, I only recently found out you can only use one), so I guess it just ignored both. Thanks for informing me the error wasn't in what I provided.

Comment: @Yifan It happens :). For loading the second application you have to manually bootstrap it through code.